# How to capture event of clicking on a bookmark

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, bookmarks, web-extension

I am writing an add-on that stores some information using [storage.local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/local) when a bookmark is created.

I would like to use that stored info when users click on the bookmark to decide how to open the url of the bookmark. However, after searching [bookmarks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks) API, I didn't find any event to capture clicking on a bookmark, because I would like to get [bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/BookmarkTreeNode) object of that bookmark.

Is there anyway I can capture the event of clicking on a bookmark?